# Focus When Program Starts, Validation for zip code MaskedTextBox and Validation for textboxes with numeric data used in calculations

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I’ve been working on this program for fun.  I’ve only had one semester of programming in VB.Net and decided to practice more because I really want to become a programmer. I have several questions on the program I have included.
1.)  For my nameTextBox I have the TabIndex = 0 and TabStop True, but I could not get the program to focus on that textbox when it started.  I finally resorted to using the subroutine below, but feel like I must have done something wrong or the focus would be on the nameTextBox.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub purchaseForm_Shown(sender As System.Object, 
          e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'When form opens, let focus be on nameTextBox.

    nameTextBox.Focus()

End Sub
```

2.)  I cannot get anything to provide validation to the zipMaskedTextBox.  I cannot figure out how to make sure it focuses on that box and raises an error message when it is passed over and left blank.
3.)  My last 3 textboxes (quantity, weight and price) need numeric entries or the program will crash.  The only validation I could make work for that was the Try/Catch blocks with the messagebox messages.  Is there anyway to use the ErrorProvider1 method like I used with the other textboxes?  I would like to keep the methods consistent.

```
'Description:   A purchase form that will enable the customer to input item, quantity and weight, 
'               returning the subtotal, sales tax and final total when the entire order is completed.  
'               Case structure will be used in parts of the program.

Public Class purchaseForm

Private quantityInteger As Integer
Private weightDecimal As Decimal
Private itemWeightDecimal As Decimal
Private totalWeightDecimal As Decimal
Private itemDescriptionString As String
Private priceDecimal As Decimal
Private itemPriceDecimal As Decimal
Private totalItemPriceecimal As Decimal
Private subtotalDecimal As Decimal
Private handlingInteger As Integer
Private totalHandlingInteger As Integer
Private Const shippingDecimal As Decimal = 0.25
Private totalShippingDecimal As Decimal
Private totalShippingAndHandlingDecimal As Decimal 'Shipping and handling combined for totalTextBox.

Private Sub purchaseForm_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'When form opens, let focus be on nameTextBox.

    nameTextBox.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub addItemButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addItemButton.Click
    'Use numeric values in calculations.

        Try
            quantityInteger = Integer.Parse(quantityTextBox.Text)
            Try
                weightDecimal = Decimal.Parse(weightTextBox.Text)
                Try
                    priceDecimal = Decimal.Parse(priceTextBox.Text)

                    'Perform the calculations

                    itemWeightDecimal = weightDecimal * quantityInteger
                    totalWeightDecimal += itemWeightDecimal
                    itemPriceDecimal = priceDecimal * quantityInteger
                    subtotalDecimal += itemPriceDecimal
                    totalShippingDecimal = shippingDecimal * totalWeightDecimal
                    'Convert numeric values back to string values to display in textboxes.

                    If quantityInteger <> 1 Then
                        weightLabel.Visible = False
                        quantityItemsWeightLabel.Visible = True
                        weightTextBox.Text = itemWeightDecimal.ToString()
                        priceLabel.Visible = False
                        quantityItemsPriceLabel.Visible = True
                        priceTextBox.Text = itemPriceDecimal.ToString("C")
                    Else
                        weightTextBox.Text = itemWeightDecimal.ToString()
                        priceTextBox.Text = itemPriceDecimal.ToString("C")
                        subtotalTextBox.Text = subtotalDecimal.ToString("C")
                        customerGroupBox.Enabled = False
                    End If

                    subtotalTextBox.Text = subtotalDecimal.ToString("C")
                    customerGroupBox.Enabled = False

                Catch priceExemption As FormatException
                    MessageBox.Show("Value must be numerical", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    With priceTextBox
                        .Focus()
                        .SelectAll()
                    End With
                End Try

            Catch weightExemption As FormatException
                MessageBox.Show("Value must be numerical", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                With weightTextBox
                    .Focus()
                    .SelectAll()
                End With
            End Try

        Catch quantityExemption As FormatException
            MessageBox.Show("Value must be numerical", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            With quantityTextBox
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
        End Try

End Sub

Private Sub clearButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
    'Clears all the data and totals for the current customer.

    descriptionTextBox.Text = String.Empty
    quantityTextBox.Text = ""
    weightLabel.Visible = True
    quantityItemsWeightLabel.Visible = False
    weightTextBox.Clear()
    priceTextBox.Text = String.Empty
    priceLabel.Visible = True
    quantityItemsPriceLabel.Visible = False
    shippingAndHandlingTextBox.Text = ""
    salesTaxTextBox.Clear()
    totalTextBox.Text = String.Empty

End Sub

Private Sub updateSummaryButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateSummaryButton.Click
    'Declare local variables.

    Dim salesTaxDecimal As Decimal = 0.08D
    Dim totalSalesTaxDecimal As Decimal
    Dim grandTotalDecimal As Decimal
    Dim totalShippingAndHandlingDecimal As Decimal
    Dim orderCompletedDialogResult As DialogResult

    orderCompletedDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure the order is completed?", "Order Completed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If orderCompletedDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

        'Determine sales tax.
        If stateTextBox.Text.ToUpper() = "CA" Then
            totalSalesTaxDecimal = salesTaxDecimal * subtotalDecimal
        Else
            totalSalesTaxDecimal = "0"
        End If

        'Create a Case structure to determine handling charges on order.

        Select Case totalWeightDecimal
            Case Is <= 10
                totalHandlingInteger = 1
            Case 11 To 100
                totalHandlingInteger = 3
            Case Is > 100
                totalHandlingInteger = 5
        End Select

        'Calculate total shipping and handling.
        totalShippingAndHandlingDecimal = totalShippingDecimal + totalHandlingInteger

        'calculate grand total

        grandTotalDecimal = subtotalDecimal + totalSalesTaxDecimal + totalShippingAndHandlingDecimal

        'convert numeric values into string values to enter shipping & handling, sales tax and the grand total into respective text boxes

        shippingAndHandlingTextBox.Text = (totalShippingDecimal + totalHandlingInteger).ToString("C")
        salesTaxTextBox.Text = totalSalesTaxDecimal.ToString("C")
        totalTextBox.Text = grandTotalDecimal.ToString("C")

        orderCompletedDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Have you printed the purchase form for the customer?", "Print", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If orderCompletedDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            'Code to clear the entire order form.
            'Call the clearButton procedure and continue from there.
            Call clearButton_Click(sender, e)

            'Continue clearing the entire form.
            nameTextBox.Text = ""
            addressTextBox.Clear()
            cityTextBox.Text = String.Empty
            stateTextBox.Text = ""
            zipMaskedTextBox.Clear()
            subtotalTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        End If
    End If

    customerGroupBox.Enabled = True
    nameTextBox.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    'Close the form

    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub ValidatingForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    'Do not allow validation to cancel the form closing.  End the program and close the form.

    e.Cancel = False

End Sub

Private Sub nameTextBox_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
    Handles nameTextBox.Validating

    Me.Focus()
    'Validate for a required entry
    'Cancel any previous error.

    ErrorProvider1.SetError(nameTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string

    If nameTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cancel the event.

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(nameTextBox, "Required Field.")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub addressTextBox_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles addressTextBox.Validating
    'Validate for a required entry.
    'Cancel any previous entry.
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(addressTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string

    If addressTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cancel the event.

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(addressTextBox, "Required field")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cityTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles cityTextBox.Validating
    'Validate for a required entry.
    'Cancel any previous entry.

    ErrorProvider1.SetError(cityTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string.

    If cityTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cancel the event.

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(cityTextBox, "Required Field")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub stateTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles stateTextBox.Validating
    'Validate for a required entry'
    'Cancels any previous entry.

    ErrorProvider1.SetError(stateTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string.

    If stateTextBox.Text.Length <> 2 Then

        'Cancel the event

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(stateTextBox, "State Abbreviation Must Be 2 Letters")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub zipMaskedTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles zipMaskedTextBox.Validating
    'Validate for a required entry.
    'Cancels any previous entry.

    ErrorProvider1.SetError(zipMaskedTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string

    If zipMaskedTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'cancel the event

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(zipMaskedTextBox, "Required Entry")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub descriptionTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles descriptionTextBox.Validating
    'Validate for a required entry
    'Cancel any previous entry.

    ErrorProvider1.SetError(descriptionTextBox, "")

    'Check for an empty string

    If descriptionTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then

        'cancel the event

        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(descriptionTextBox, "Entry Required")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: 1) check which control does get the focus 2) Just check the zip when they click the button 3)  Instead of Try/Catch, use the `.TryParse` methods when converting user text to numeric (+1 for NOT using Val!).  You could also check all the fields and set the results in ErrorProvider for ALL errors instead of one at a time.  The code will be nested less as well.

Comment: 1.) The focus is on the addItemButton but I don't know why. I have never made that button the focus at any point in the program, and it is #9 in the TabIndex.  2.) I don't know what you mean when you said to "just check the zip".  Anything I've tried to use to check doesn't work.  3.)  I'd really like to get +1 for not using Val, but, since I'm not sure what you mean, I probably shouldn't.  what is the .TryParse method. Remember, I'm a newbie and still learning.  I've got more questions, but I have run out of room for this comment. I'll have to save the rest for my next one.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to set the results in ErrorProvider for ALL errors instead of one at a time.  I thought I was doing good doing one at a time, lol!  I've still obviously got a lot to learn.  Any more information you could give me would be very appreciated.

Comment: the button must have a lower focus index (dont spend a lot of time setting focus - let the user do what they will). 2) when they click the button just validate the zipcode(?) text box there.  3) For TryParse, use Decimal.TryParse instead of Parse, it will combine PArse and what you are trying to do this the stack of Try/Catch.  For the ErrProvider, what I meant was before you calc and test each input call a procedure to check everything and set the EP.  Then only calc if there are no errors (ie your function returns true).  That way a) the user gets all the errs b) u know all is ok to calc